# curl: (2) Failed Initialization

Tags: linux, curl

I have installed libcurl 7.33.0 on Linux. I used the following commands to install:

```
./configure  
make  
make install
```

If I run `curl http://www.google.com` I get following error:
**curl: (2) Failed initialization**

curl is installed at /usr/local/bin and header files at /usr/local/include/curl.

curl-config:

```
sandesh@ubuntu:~$ curl-config --features  
IPv6  
libz  
sandesh@ubuntu:~$ curl-config --protocols  
DICT  
FILE  
FTP  
GOPHER    
HTTP  
IMAP  
POP3  
RTSP  
SMTP  
TELNET  
TFTP  
sandesh@ubuntu:~$ curl-config --ca  
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  
sandesh@ubuntu:~$ curl-config --cflags  
-I/usr/local/include  
sandesh@ubuntu:~$ curl-config --configure  

sandesh@ubuntu:~$ curl-config --libs  
-L/usr/local/lib -lcurl  
sandesh@ubuntu:~$ curl-config --static-libs  
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a -lz -lrt
```

I believe it is something to do with my configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a wild guess, you've linked the `/usr/local/bin/curl` binary to the system curl library.

To verify that this is the case, you should do:

```
ldd /usr/local/bin/curl
```

If it indicates a line like:

```
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fea7e889000)
```

It means that the curl binary is picking up the system curl library. While it was linked at compile time to the correct library, at run-time it's picking up the incorrect library, which seems to be a pretty typical reason for this error happening.

If you run the configure with `--disable-shared`, then it will produce a `.a`, which, when linked to the curl binary will not depend on the system `libcurl.so`, but will instead have it's own private code.

If you're cross-compiling, then you'll also need to cross-compile all the dependent libraries, and that is another question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I get the following on running ldd /usr/local/bin/curl:  libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0xb808e000)

Comment: I compiled using --disable-shared option and it is working fine now. If the target system is not having system curl library then the curl with shared library should work right?

Comment: Yes, if there's no curl shared library on the target system, then it should pick up the library installed in /usr/local/lib by your installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does include `curl` by default as far as I know. So if you don't need specifically the 7.33.0 version, then purge it and install it again from the repository.

```
#remove everything you had with curl
sudo apt-get purge curl
#optional update
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
#install it from repository
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: Comment if you need that exact version, I will delete my post in that case. Otherwise let me know if it started working for you ;)

Comment: I want to compile and install curl on my linux machine as at later stage I want to use the same source to compile for arm-linux arch.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could help me in resolving with the issue.

Comment: You didn't say that. This is advice for Ubuntu on which you're currently running. Try to ask this question on http://superuser.com/ or ask the mods to move it there. Cheers!