# curl giving the error "`curl: (2) Failed initialization"

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl, system-administration

I have two curls, one that comes with the OS, and another that comes with an application I installed. When I try run the one that comes with the application, I get "`curl: (2) Failed initialization", what is the problem here?

Comment: the curl that comes with application maybe uses common libs of the system, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331418/curl-2-failed-initialization

Comment: Yes it does. But I don't have the option of recompiling. Do I need to reinstall the OS's curl to match that of the application's?

Comment: uninstall the system curl and put yours as default

Comment: Ok, is there an alternative way?

Comment: Have you try creating a symbolic link from system default curl to your application curl?

Comment: for example, get backup of application curl, remove it, and create a symbolic link from the system default curl

Comment: Not yet, but thanks for the suggestion.