# Curl Initialization error with git pre-push hook

Tags: git, shell, curl, githooks

I created a git pre-push hook to check the commits being pushed. 
One of the validation steps fetches some data using cURL for validating the commit. On running git push, cURL fails to initialize with error

```
curl: (2) Failed initialization
```

The pre-push hook has the correct permissions (-rwx------). To narrow down the problem I removed everything from the script except the cURL command and I am able to reproduce the error with a very simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/curl "http://www.google.com"
```

The script works as expected when run standalone.

Additional details:

i. Git already added to path

ii. Curl version: curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check what `curl` is using with `ldd /usr/bin/curl`, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20332546/6309)

As seen [in this issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/122#issue-34319338), you might then need to adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to reference what library is actually used.

Comment: I am able to run curl from the shell without any errors. I get initialization error only from git hooks. I also tried setting up a pre-commit  hook, I get the same error.   `ldd /usr/bin/curl | grep libcurl.so.4`                              
`libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f7e7e53b000)`

Comment: @arpitpanwar What is your OS (`uname -a`, `cat /etc/os-release`) and Git version?

Comment: @arpitpanwar interesting read: http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=52037, https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1613

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article. I read it and tried reinstalling curl but still no luck. Moreover I plan on giving out the pre-push script to other people so I don't want the setup to be too hard.  `uname -a` , `Linux <hostname> 3.2.45-0.6.wd.865.49.315.metal1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 1 10:12:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.  Git version 2.7.3.AMZN.

Comment: Any possibility to upgrade git to 2.12.2? (Just to see if the issue persists)